# SQL Server fails on converting string to datetime with valid string

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm migrating some old, horribly-formatted data to a new system, and am extracting expiry dates from a mass of data in a string column. It has the format `<Something>Data</>` (not my doing, I'll add!)

One of the elements I need to extract is an expiry date/time. I do it as follows:

```
SELECT convert(datetime,
  SUBSTRING(EventData,
            CHARINDEX('<ExpiryDate>', EventData, 0) + 12,
            CHARINDEX('</>', EventData, CHARINDEX('<ExpiryDate>', EventData, 0)) - (CHARINDEX('<ExpiryDate>', EventData, 0) + 12)
  ),
  103)
```

This works fine in most cases, albeit a bit slow, but on some data I get the error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

This would make sense if the substring was returning incorrectly formatted date/times, but they all seem fine to me. Ensuring the order, the following lines are processed, with the last failing:

```
<ExpiryDate>22/03/2010 17:00:00</>
<ExpiryDate>22/03/2010 17:00:00</>
<ExpiryDate>22/03/2010 17:00:00</>
<ExpiryDate>22/03/2010 17:00:00</>
```

The substring quite happily parses them as follows:

```
22/03/2010 17:00:00
22/03/2010 17:00:00
22/03/2010 17:00:00
22/03/2010 17:00:00
```

Is there any reason that the last of these four would be failing? Or is there a more robust way to parse them?

Edit: Some more investigation has revealed an oddity: If I don't CONVERT() inline, but instead just assign the output of the substring, and use that as a CTE to then perform the CONVERT() on, it works just fine. Something feels off with the data types.

Comment: Perhaps not related, but is there a reason why you aren't converting to `datetime2`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on SQL server 2012, worked perfect. The CONVERT date format 103 is correct. Does the below code work on your database?

```
DECLARE @MyString CHAR(100)
SET @MyString = '<ExpiryDate>22/03/2010 17:00:00</>'

SELECT convert(datetime,
  SUBSTRING(@MyString,
        CHARINDEX('<ExpiryDate>', @MyString, 0) + 12,
        CHARINDEX('</>', @MyString, CHARINDEX('<ExpiryDate>', @MyString, 0)) -        
         (CHARINDEX('<ExpiryDate>', @MyString, 0) + 12)
  )
,  103)
```

Comment: It does work, yes. That's the odd thing. Anything outside of pulling it directly seems to work fine.

Something I've noticed though, is that if I set the substring output as the column contents, assign that with a WITH clause, then convert afterwards then it's fine. That makes me think there's a data type issue going on.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you any further without the error generating data. As far as I can tell, your code is 100% correct. I would also look into the data itself. Perhaps an invisible character (TAB, CR, LF, ...) somewhere? Seems you have found a solution by using CTE. As Daniel B mentioned, you could use datatime2. It has some advantages over datetime.